# Writing to a file after one by one process completes in python

Tags: python, csv, multiprocessing, mpi, python-multiprocessing

**Context:**
I have large(30mb now but later it may be over gigabytes) csv file (with 185 line) that to be searched for some value (each element of `times`) chunk by chunk ( chunk of 6 value of csv) by rows and if found it to be written in the another file. i.e. get one element from `times` sorted deque and search in another deque (i.e. `rdr = deque(reder)`) by 6 element in `rdr` if found write to the file and continue for the next elemnt in the `times` deque.

**Problem:**
I have already written a code that does the work perfectly but it is so-so slow (8 hrs). I want better performance. I think of multiprocessing - i am not getting through and thus seek help. I used a function `ddd` that gets all arguments from the calling scope except `times1` that i pass explicitly.

**Code i tried with:**

```
dim = [0,76,'1.040000',1,1,'1.000000']+min_max_ret(X,Y)
times = deque(sorted(list(timestep),key=lambda x:ast.literal_eval(x)))

def ddd(times1):# ddd(outfl, rdr, acc_ret, FR_XY, width, length) all these arguments are get from the calling scope.
    for tim in times1:
        time = ['{0:.6f}'.format(ast.literal_eval(tim)/1000.000000)]
        outfl.writelines([u'2 ********* TIMESTEP']+['\n']+time+['\n'])
        for index,line in enumerate(rdr):
            if index!=0:
                cnt = 8
                for counter in [qq for qq in [line[jj:jj+6] for jj in range(8,len(line),6)] if len(qq)==6]:
                    counter = map(unicode.strip,counter)
                    if counter[5]==tim:
                        cr_id = line[0]
                        acc = '{0:.6f}'.format(acc_ret(counter[3], counter[4]))
                        car_ltlng = map(unicode.strip,[line[cnt],line[cnt+1],line[cnt+6],line[cnt+7]])
                        xy = FR_XY(*car_ltlng)
                        data = [3]+[cr_id]+[1,1]+xy+[length,width]+[counter[2]]+[acc]
                        outfl.writelines([unicode(ww).strip()+'\n' for ww in data]) 
                        cnt+=6
        print "Time is %s is completed"%tim

with open(r"C:\my_output_ascii_14Dec.trj",'w') as outfl:
    with open(fl,'r') as inf:
        reder = csv.reader(inf,delimiter=';')
        rdr = deque(reder)
        outfl.writelines([str(w)+'\n' for w in dim])
        p = Pool(5)
        p.map(ddd,times)#[[xx for xx in islice(times,ii,ii+10)] for ii in range(0,len(times))])
```

Sample csv content:

```
car_id; car_type; entry_gate; entry_time(ms); exit_gate; exit_time(ms); traveled_dist(m); avg_speed(m/s); trajectory(x[m];y[m];speed[m/s];a_tangential[ms-2];a_lateral[ms-2];timestamp[ms];)
24; Bus; 25; 4300.00; 26; 48520.00; 118.47; 2.678999; 509552.78; 5039855.59; 10.0740; 0.4290; 0.2012; 0.0000; 509552.97; 5039855.57; 10.0821; 0.3853; 0.2183; 20.0000; 509553.17; 5039855.55; 10.0886; 0.2636; 0.2356; 40.0000; 509553.37; 5039855.53; 10.0927; 0.1420; 0.2532; 60.0000; 509553.57; 5039855.51; 10.0943; 0.0203; 0.2710; 80.0000; 509553.76; 5039855.48; 10.0935; -0.1014; 0.2890; 100.0000; 509553.96; 5039855.46; 10.0902; -0.2231; 0.3073; 120.0000; 509554.16; 5039855.44; 10.0846; -0.3448; 0.3257; 140.0000; 509554.36; 5039855.42; 10.0765; -0.4665; 0.3444; 160.0000; 509554.56; 5039855.40; 10.0659; -0.5881; 0.3633; 180.0000; 509554.76; 5039855.37; 10.0529; -0.7098; 0.3823; 200.0000; 509554.96; 5039855.35; 10.0375; -0.8315; 0.4016; 220.0000; 509555.17; 5039855.33; 10.0197; -0.9532; 0.4211; 240.0000; 509555.37;
```

Partial csv file at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02dwetdumf8tj79/output.csv?dl=0).

Comment: Does it have to be a csv file? Probably using a SQLite database would be much faster.

Comment: Nops i get csv (`;` delimited) and have to process.

Comment: Could you post some lines of a sample csv file to make it easier to understand how your file looks like?

Comment: re: comment from @Randrian - Just because you *receive* a CSV file does not necessarily preclude you from dumping it into a database so you can process it that way.

Comment: @ Gord Thompson- i have to share this python script in different machine that entails possibility of the dumb operators.

Comment: A working example code would really help to understand your problem. You have some undefined variables/functions in your code. Also is there any reason you did use the *csvkit* module and not the *csv* one ?

Comment: OK edited the question..